# Tangent line and $x$-intercept for exponential function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have the function $y(x)=Ae^{-\frac{x}{x_0}}$ and the graph:

[image]

I know if $x=0$ I have $y(0)=Ae^0=A$.

**Questions 1:** Why is $x_0$ where the graph crosses the $x$-axis?

*Attempt*:

If $y=0$ I have $0=Ae^{-\frac{x}{x_0}}$ and 
$$
\ln 0=\ln (Ae^{-\frac{x}{x_0}})=\ln A-\frac{x}{x_0}
$$
But $A=1$ so $\ln A=0$ and also $\ln 0=1$ so 
$$
1=-\frac{x}{x_0}\\
x_0=-x
$$
Stuck here, what is the meaning of $x_0=-x$?

**Question 2:** How can I find the tangent line for $y(x)$?

Comment: I don't understand your interpretation for Q1. Also note that $\ln 0$ is not defined.

Comment: Note that $y(x)=Ae^{-\frac{x}{x_0}} \implies \log y = -\frac x{x_0}$ and as $x\to \infty$ we have $\log y \to -\infty$ wich is consistent with$ y\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$y'(x)=-\frac A{x_0}e^{-\frac x{x_0}} \implies y'(0)=-\frac A{x_0}$$

then the tangent line at $x=0$ is

$$y-A=-\frac A{x_0}(x-0) \iff y=-\frac A{x_0}\cdot x+A$$

which gives for $y=0$

$$0=-\frac A{x_0}\cdot x+A \implies x=x_0$$

and more in general the tangent at a point $x=\bar x$ is given by

$$y-Ae^{-\frac {\bar x}{x_0}}=-\frac A{x_0}e^{-\frac {\bar x}{x_0}}(x-\bar x) \iff y=-\frac A{x_0}e^{-\frac {\bar x}{x_0}}\cdot x+\frac A{x_0}e^{-\frac {\bar x}{x_0}}\cdot \bar x+Ae^{-\frac {\bar x}{x_0}}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks! I tried to find the $x$-intercept without calculus, isn't possible? Is calculus a must for both Q1 and Q2?

Comment: We need it to evaluate the slope!